# How to replicate the iOS Chrome tabs effect with a UICollectionView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm creating an App in which one of the views is a UICollectionView inside a UIView. I'm trying to replicate the Chrome for iOS effect when all the active tabs are in view, like this:

[image: Chrome for iOS open tabs view]

Does anyone has an idea on how to accomplish this with a UICollectionView o has a link to a tutorial or something that could help?

Comment: To be honest this looks like it could be done with a UITableView. It simply looks complicated because of the artwork, there is quite a bit of custom drawing.

Comment: I thought that too, but since my project already has the UICollectionView set up, I thought that an approach using it would be simpler than recoding all to get it to work with a UITableView.

Answer (score 3):

I have a couple of links that may help!

[Sample Code #1](https://github.com/KieranLafferty/KLNoteViewController)

[Sample Code #2](https://github.com/graetzer/SGTabs)

Comment: The first one seems to be what I need. I'll give it a try, thanks!