# UICollectionViewLayout for Google Chrome (iOS App) Tab Switcher-like UI

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uicollectionviewlayout

My project needs a UI like Google Chrome's Tab Switcher. There was such a question in the past but the responses are mostly irrelevant, as it was written 5 years ago and the responses had to do with a static and overlapping Evernote UI ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15824256/how-to-replicate-the-ios-chrome-tabs-effect-with-a-uicollectionview)). I've been trying for days, but the best I could get was something really sluggish. Also interestingly, when coded, at some areas it worked, then it didn't. I didn't choose any code because honestly my code probably is more wrong than right and I should start fresh from the beginning. [image: Kind of like this]

What is it that makes it so confusing? Bottom down must be initially 100% visible, next up 50%, next 25% (relative to their height) and also obviously it's scrollable. The scroll direction like chrome is first (latest) at bottom and last at the top. However, I would also like the distance between the first and second to increase, should you scroll down to see less recent views, the second would have to be able to be 100% visible, as the bottom app disappears off screen. [image: This concept is the end goal...]

Yes, it's a jailbreak project but that's irrelevant as I've coded a replica in the iOS simulator for this part. It's just a layout problem for a UICollectionView. All of the rest of the project, has been coded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you can you the following library to achieve the desired result.
[StickyCollectionView-Swift](https://github.com/matbeich/StickyCollectionView-Swift)